# Android - How to you CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider for authenticated user?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I need to upload file to S3 as authenticated user. I have managed to get token from the CognitoUserPool as CognitoUser.

Here is the code.

```
String poolId = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    String clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    String clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";

// Create a CognitoUserPool object to refer to your user pool
CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool(getApplicationContext(), poolId, clientId, clientSecret,Regions.XX_XXXX_X);

CognitoUser user = userPool.getUser();

user.getSessionInBackground(authenticationHandler);
```

and below is the AuthenticationHandler callback.

```
final AuthenticationHandler authenticationHandler = new 
AuthenticationHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(CognitoUserSession cognitoUserSession, CognitoDevice cognitoDevice) {

            Log.d("success",cognitoUserSession.getAccessToken().getJWTToken());

        }

        @Override
        public void getAuthenticationDetails(AuthenticationContinuation authenticationContinuation, String userId) {
            // The API needs user sign-in credentials to continue
            AuthenticationDetails authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails("test", "test", null);

            // Pass the user sign-in credentials to the continuation
            authenticationContinuation.setAuthenticationDetails(authenticationDetails);

            // Allow the sign-in to continue
            authenticationContinuation.continueTask();
        }

       ...


        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
            // Sign-in failed, check exception for the cause
            Log.d("Error here",exception.toString());
        }
    };
```

Am i supposed to save these tokens in the SharedPereference by myself? or is there any other way around.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can someone please explain how do i get clientSecret ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process for linking a user pools user with your identity pool is described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html

```
cognitoUser.getSessionInBackground(new AuthenticationHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(CognitoUserSession session) {
        String idToken = session.getIdToken().getJWTToken();

        Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
        logins.put(cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<YOUR_USER_POOL_ID>, session.getIdToken().getJWTToken());
        credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
        credentialsProvider.refresh();
    }
```

});

Comment: can someone please explain how do i get clientSecret ?

Comment: Hi @jeff Can you please explain how to create credentialsProvider object. What is the type of credentialsProvider object. Documentation has not covered these things.